# UIActivityViewController cannot share image

Tags: ios, swift

I share image this way

```
if let image = viewModels[indexPath.row].image, let viewController = viewController {
    let objectsToShare = [image]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    viewController.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and on my device, it works correctly. But on one other device, I see next behaviour:

1) Image is displaying on screen correctly

2) Activity controller appears

3) When user tries to share the image to app (telegram or whatsapp, for example) activity controller show list of people but when he select sharing target, controller freeze for a second and then disappears (image hasn't been sent to target)

4) Saving image to photo working good.

What is this can be? Internal IOS bug, or something wrong with UIImage instance, for example? IOS version 11.4 on both devices

Comment: What is the type of `image`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behaviour, when tried to share the empty text file. After filtering for only non empty text, i start be enable to send to telegram and whatsapp. It seems, that when you try to share something with 0 bytes length it provokes an error. Check your image please.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code when share image to messenger or chat tool

it works for me

```
func share(withUiImage uiImage : UIImage?){

    if let safeImage: UIImage = uiImage,let imagePngData = safeImage.pngData() {

        let activityViewController  = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Share Image",imagePngData], applicationActivities: nil)

        if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.maxY, width: 0, height: 0)
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
        }


        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
}
```

Comment: The issue for me was sharing the uiimage, if you share the data it works